# Electric flux through a cylinder's side

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, gauss-law

[image]

We have a cylinder with radius $R$, as shown above, and a point charge $Q$. We want to calculate the electric flux passing through the cylinder's side surface, excluding its caps.

Is there a way to do this with Gauss's formula? Or should I double integrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total flux out of the cylinder must be zero.  You can use Gauss's law (reduced with solid angles) to find the flux in and out through spherical caps at each end of the cylinder.  The difference must go out through the sides.